# PHP When rewrite pages url then the $_get not working

Tags: php, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am using this [URL rewriting with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php) The Folder structure for rewriting the URLs. I am done it is working fine but after rewrite the URL the `$_GET['cat_id']` is not working. How to get the data now? please help. My project is here [http://199.192.21.232/~admin/category/men-items](http://199.192.21.232/%7Eadmin/category/men-items)

Script

```
define( 'INCLUDE_DIR', dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/' );

$rules = array( 
    'picture'   => "/picture/(?'text'[^/]+)/(?'id'\d+)",    // '/picture/some-text/51'
    'album'     => "/album/(?'album'[\w\-]+)",              // '/album/album-slug'
    'category'  => "/category/(?'category'[\w\-]+)",        // '/category/category-slug'
    'page'      => "/page/(?'page'about|contact)",          // '/page/about', '/page/contact'
    'post'      => "/(?'post'[\w\-]+)",                     // '/post-slug'
    'home'      => "/"                                      // '/'
);

$uri = rtrim( dirname($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]), '/' );
$uri = '/' . trim( str_replace( $uri, '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ), '/' );
$uri = urldecode( $uri );

foreach ( $rules as $action => $rule ) {
    if ( preg_match( '~^'.$rule.'$~i', $uri, $params ) ) {
        include( INCLUDE_DIR . $action . '.php' );
        exit();
    }
}

include( INCLUDE_DIR . '404.php' );
```

HTaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/.*$ index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: What is the URL you are requesting? Where is the `.htaccess` file located? Where is this `cat_id` URL parameter you speak of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code you posted there is no `$_GET['cat_id']` variable, unless there is a `cat_id` URL parameter on the URL being requested (which you've not stated).

If the `.htaccess` file and `index.php` script are located at `http://example.com/~admin/` (where `~admin` is an Apache per-user web directory) then a request of the form `http://example.com/~admin/category/men-items` (as in your example) would result in the `$params['category']` array index holding the value `men-items` (from the named captured group in the matching regex). If that is what you are referring to? But there is no "cat_id" here.

---

**UPDATE:**

> I just want now i have two links now on my website 1: `/~admin/category.php?cat_id=2` and 2: `/~admin/category/men-items`. it will create content duplicate issue in feature i want just one link like 2: `/~admin/category/men-items` so need to redirect 1 link to 2

To canonicalise the URL for SEO you can do something like the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cat_id=2$
RewriteRule ^category\.php$ /~admin/category/men-items [R=301,L]
```

If the old URL `category.php` still exists as a physical file then you'll need to ensure that MultiViews is disabled in order to avoid conflicts with mod_rewrite. For example, at the very top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Comment: ok now i have two urls one is simple url like /~admin/category.php?cat_id=2 and second rewrited url /~admin/category/men-items so how to redirect the first url to second url? or just the first url should not work because of duplicates content issues.

Comment: Do you need the `cat_id` (ie. `2`) in your script? To clarify, you are linking to `/~admin/category/men-items` (not `/~admin/category.php?cat_id=2`)?

Comment: No i already fixed the cat_id issue. I got all data from $params it is fine now. I just want now i have two links now on my website ``` 1: /~admin/category.php?cat_id=2 ``` and ``` 2: /~admin/category/men-items ``` it will create content duplicate issue in feature i want just one link like ``` 2: /~admin/category/men-items ``` so need to redirect 1 link to 2 or just 1 link should not work or redirect to 404. My new question is here [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64835027/php-when-rewrite-pages-urls-how-to-remove-or-redirect-category-phpcat-id-2-urls

Comment: I've updated my answer with a canonical redirect (for SEO) from #1 to #2.