# PHP When rewrite pages urls how to remove or redirect category.php?cat_id=2 urls to rewrited urls?

Tags: php, redirect, url-rewriting

I am using this [URL rewriting with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php) The Folder structure for rewriting the URLs. I am done it is working fine but after rewrite the URLs then ok now i have two URLs one is simple URL like `/~admin/product-category.php?cat_id=2` and second rewrites URL `/~admin/product-category/men-items` so how to redirect the first URL to second URL? or just the first URL should not work because of duplicates content issues.

My Project Links:

First link: [http://199.192.21.232/~admin/product-category.php?cat_id=2](http://199.192.21.232/%7Eadmin/product-category.php?cat_id=2)
Rewrites link: [http://199.192.21.232/~admin/product-category/men-items](http://199.192.21.232/%7Eadmin/product-category/men-items)

Script

```
define( 'INCLUDE_DIR', dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/' );

$rules = array( 
    'picture'   => "/picture/(?'text'[^/]+)/(?'id'\d+)",    // '/picture/some-text/51'
    'album'     => "/album/(?'album'[\w\-]+)",              // '/album/album-slug'
    'category'  => "/product-category/(?'product_category'[\w\-]+)",        // '/category/category-slug'
    'page'      => "/page/(?'page'about|contact)",          // '/page/about', '/page/contact'
    'post'      => "/(?'post'[\w\-]+)",                     // '/post-slug'
    'home'      => "/"                                      // '/'
);

$uri = rtrim( dirname($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]), '/' );
$uri = '/' . trim( str_replace( $uri, '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ), '/' );
$uri = urldecode( $uri );

foreach ( $rules as $action => $rule ) {
    if ( preg_match( '~^'.$rule.'$~i', $uri, $params ) ) {
        include( INCLUDE_DIR . $action . '.php' );
        exit();
    }
}

include( INCLUDE_DIR . '404.php' );
```

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What is the `category.php` here? Some existing PHP file? Where are you trying to put this code? Do you understand anything of that code you are trying to use?

Comment: yes ``` category.php is existing PHP file. i am using it for rewrite pages you can check it here the The Folder structure for rewriting the URLs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php

Comment: I saw that SO thread, you have a link to it in your question. Where are you trying to put this code? Do you understand how that code supposed to work? Do you understand that rewritten URI will be processed by `index.php` rather that `category.php` having that `.htaccess`? What is the purpose of that `category.php` at all? Why do not generate all the links right way initially?

Comment: Yes i understand i just update my question please check the links provided. this code and everything is working fine. i just want to remove or redirect the First link to Rewrites link. because it is creating duplicate content issue google will index both URLs i just want one URL like http://199.192.21.232/~admin/product-category/men-items

Comment: As I understand, the `/~admin/product-category.php?cat_id=2` URI is served with the `/~admin/product-category.php` PHP script, and the rewritten `/~admin/product-category/men-items` URI should be served with the same PHP script too. Having that `.htaccess` the rewritten link would be served with your `index.php` rather than `product-category.php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how the referred code example supposed to work:

**product-category.php**

```php
<?php
define( 'INCLUDE_DIR', dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/' );

$rules = array( 
    'redirect-category'  => "/product-category\\.php\\?cat_id=(?'category'\\d+)"
);

$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$uri = urldecode( $uri );

foreach ( $rules as $action => $rule ) {
    if ( preg_match( '#'.$rule.'#', $uri, $params ) ) {
        include( INCLUDE_DIR . $action . '.php' );
        exit();
    }
}
```

**redirect-category.php**

```php
<?php
$categories = array(
    2 => 'men-items'
);
header("Location: " . preg_replace( '#'.$rule.'#', "/product_category/{$categories[$params['category']]}/", $uri ));
```

Comment: This code redirecting  /~admin/product-category.php?cat_id=2 to /~admin/product-category/men-items ??

Comment: It is supposed to. However that `/~admin/product-category/men-items` request in turn will be served by `index.php`, and if you want to serve it with `product-category.php` you shoud do it via the `.htaccess`. I don't know how to do it properly, I've adandoned apache in favor of nginx many years ago.

Comment: ok thank you for your help but i just want if someone visite to this url /~admin/product-category.php?cat_id=2 so redirect it to /~admin/product-category/men-items

Answer (score 1):

At the top of your htaccess , put the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cat_id=2$ [NC]
RewriteRule category.php$ http://199.192.21.232/~admin/product-category/men-items? [L,R=302]
```

This will redirect `http://199.192.21.232/~admin/product-category.php?cat_id=2` to `http://199.192.21.232/~admin/product-category/men-items` .

In case you have multiple old URLs with the same queryString , just change the condition pattern from `^cat_id=2$` to `^cat_id=.+$` .
When you are sure the redirect is working fine  change `R=302` to `R=301` to make the Redirection permanent .