# PHP rewrite rules page with slug dash like page-about not working

Tags: php, regex, url-rewriting

This code is working fine but the problem is dash - if i add a page in single text named like `'category'  => "/category/(?'category'[\w\-]+)",`  it is working fine and when i want to add the dash like this `'product-category'  => "/product-category/(?'product-category'[\w\-]+)",` then it is not working. What i am missing?

```
define( 'INCLUDE_DIR', dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/' );

$rules = array( 
    'picture'           => "/picture/(?'text'[^/]+)/(?'id'\d+)",              // '/picture/some-text/51'
    'album'             => "/album/(?'album'[\w\-]+)",                        // '/album/album-slug'
    'product-category'  => "/product-category/(?'product-category'[\w\-]+)",  // '/product-category/category-slug'
    'product'           => "/product/(?'product'[\w\-]+)",                    // '/product/product-slug'
    'page'              => "/page/(?'page'about|contact)",                    // '/page/about', '/page/contact'
    'post'              => "/(?'post'[\w\-]+)",                               // '/post-slug'
    'home'              => "/"                                                // '/'
);

$uri = rtrim( dirname($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]), '/' );
$uri = '/' . trim( str_replace( $uri, '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ), '/' );
$uri = urldecode( $uri );

foreach ( $rules as $action => $rule ) {
    if ( preg_match( '~^'.$rule.'$~i', $uri, $params ) ) {
        include( INCLUDE_DIR . $action . '.php' );
        exit();
    }
}

include INCLUDE_DIR . 'header.php'; 
include INCLUDE_DIR . '404.php';
include INCLUDE_DIR . 'footer.php';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use only [valid](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php) PHP variable names for the regex named capture groups. The dash character (`-`) is not allowed to use in the variable name, and somewhere in your PHP logs you have the `Compilation failed: syntax error in subpattern name` warning. You can change that dash to underscore to have a valid named capture group name:

```
'product-category'  => "/product-category/(?'product_category'[\w\-]+)",  // '/product-category/category-slug'
```

Comment: Can you help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64835027/php-when-rewrite-pages-urls-how-to-remove-or-redirect-category-phpcat-id-2-urls